# Asynchronous, composable return value for vector/stream data in Java 9

Tags: java, rx-java, nonblocking, java-9, reactive-streams

Say I have an API that, based on some query criteria, will find or construct a widget:

```
Widget getMatchingWidget(WidgetCriteria c) throws Throwable
```

The (synchronous) client code looks like:

```
try {
  Widget w = getMatchingWidget(criteria);
  processWidget(w);
} catch (Throwable t) {
  handleError(t);
}
```

Now say finding or constructing a widget is unpredictably expensive, and I don't want clients to block while waiting for it. So I change it to:

```
CompletableFuture<Widget> getMatchingWidget(WidgetCriteria c)
```

Clients can then write either:

```
CompletableFuture<Widget> f = getMatchingWidget(criteria);
f.thenAccept(this::processWidget)
f.exceptionally(t -> { handleError(t); return null; })
```

or:

```
getMatchingWidget(criteria).whenComplete((t, w) -> {
  if (t != null) { handleError(t); }
  else { processWidget(t); }
});
```

Now, let's say instead the synchronous API can return *0 to n widgets:*

```
Stream<Widget> getMatchingWidgets(WidgetCriteria c)
```

Naively, I could write:

```
CompletableFuture<Stream<Widget>> getMatchingWidgets(WidgetCriteria c)
```

However, this doesn't actually make the code non-blocking, it just pushes the blocking around -- either the `Future` blocks until all the `Widgets` are available, or the code that iterates over the `Stream` blocks waiting for each `Widget`. What I want is something that will let me process each widget as they arrive, something like:

```
void forEachMatchingWidget(WidgetCriteria c, Consumer<Widget> widgetProcessor)
```

But this doesn't offer error handling, and even if I add an additional `Consumer<Throwable> errorHandler`, it doesn't let me, for instance, compose my widget retrieval with other queries, or transform the results.

So I'm looking for some composable thing that combines the characteristics of a `Stream` (iterability, transformability) with the characteristics of a `CompletableFuture` (asynchronous result and error handling). (And, while we're at it, back pressure might be nice.)

Is this a [java.util.concurrent.Flow.Publisher](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Flow.Publisher.html)? An [io.reactivex.Observable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html)? Something more complicated? Something simpler?

Comment: I'd tend to push things into a queue, and pull things out of the queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use case falls very naturally into the world that RxJava is addressing. If we have an observable:

```
Observable<Widget> getMatchingWidgets(wc);
```

that produces zero or more widgets based on the criteria, then you can process each widget as it appears using:

```
getMatchingWidgets(wc)
  .subscribeOn( backgroundScheduler )
  .subscribe( w -> processWidget(w),
              error -> handleError(error) );
```

The observable chain will run on the `backgroundScheduler`, which is often a wrapper for a thread-pool executor service. If you need to do the final processing of each widget in your UI, you can use the `observeOn()` operator to switch over to the UI scheduler before processing:

```
getMatchingWidgets(wc)
  .subscribeOn( backgroundScheduler )
  .observeOn( uiScheduler )
  .subscribe( w -> processWidget(w),
              error -> handleError(error) );
```

To me, the elegance of the RxJava approach is that it handles so many of the nuts and bolts of pipeline management in a fluent manner. Looking at that observer chain, you know exactly what is happening and where.